# PySpark: How to add columns whose data come from a query (similar to subquery for each row)

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a holidays table

- start: Date
- end: Date
- type: Enum(HOLIDAY|LONG_WEEKENDS)

Some example data:

```
"start","end","type"
"2019-01-01","2019-01-01","HOLIDAY"
"2019-02-05","2019-02-06","HOLIDAY"
"2019-03-16","2019-03-24","HOLIDAY"
"2019-04-19","2019-04-19","HOLIDAY"
"2019-10-04","2019-10-04","HOLIDAY"
"2019-08-08","2019-08-13","LONG_WEEKENDS"
"2019-10-25","2019-10-29","LONG_WEEKENDS"
"2019-12-20","2020-01-02","LONG_WEEKENDS"
```

And a flights table, for simplicity, it has

- id: varchar
- out_date: Date
- in_date: Date

Some example data:

```
"id","out_date","in_date"
"25997661","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"
"25997658","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"
"25997659","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"
"25997662","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"
"25997663","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"
"25997657","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"
"25997660","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"
"25997397","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"
```

I want to add 4 columns into the flights table like:

- out_date_is_holiday: Boolean
- out_date_is_longweekends: Boolean
- in_date_is_holiday: Boolean
- in_date_is_longweekends: Boolean

So the "stupid" way is I download the holidays table. Then for each flight, I will do (in pyspark):

- add column `out_date_is_holiday if out_date is between holidays.start and holidays.end AND holidays.type = 'HOLIDAYS' then true else false`

Likewise for the other 3 columns. How can I do this efficiently? I am doing this on AWS Glue, if it matters

**UPDATE**

Following @stack0114106 suggestion, I tried:

```
WITH t (
    SELECT  
        f.outboundlegid,
        f.inboundlegid,
        f.agent,
        f.querydatetime,
        CASE WHEN type = 'HOLIDAY' AND (out_date BETWEEN start AND end)
            THEN true
            ELSE false
            END out_is_holiday,
        CASE WHEN type = 'LONG_WEEKENDS' AND (out_date BETWEEN start AND end)
            THEN true
            ELSE false
            END out_is_longweekends,
        CASE WHEN type = 'HOLIDAY' AND (in_date BETWEEN start AND end)
            THEN true
            ELSE false
            END in_is_holiday,
        CASE WHEN type = 'LONG_WEEKENDS' AND (in_date BETWEEN start AND end)
            THEN true
            ELSE false
            END in_is_longweekends
    FROM flights f
    CROSS JOIN holidays h
)
SELECT 
    f.*, 
    CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(out_is_holiday), true)
        THEN true
        ELSE false
        END out_is_holiday,
    CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(out_is_longweekends), true)
        THEN true
        ELSE false
        END out_is_longweekends,
    CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(in_is_holiday), true)
        THEN true
        ELSE false
        END in_is_holiday,
    CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(in_is_longweekends), true)
        THEN true
        ELSE false
        END in_is_longweekends
FROM t f
GROUP BY 
    f.querydatetime, 
    f.outboundlegid,
    f.inboundlegid,
    f.agent
LIMIT 1000000
```

But got

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"expression 'f.`out_is_holiday`' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;;\nGlobalLimit 1000000\n+- LocalLimit 1000000\n +- Aggregate [querydatetime#231, outboundlegid#208, inboundlegid#209, agent#205], [outboundlegid#208, inboundlegid#209, agent#205, querydatetime#231, out_is_holiday#347, out_is_longweekends#348, in_is_holiday#349, in_is_longweekends#350, CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(out_is_holiday#347, 0, 0), true) THEN true ELSE false END AS out_is_holiday#343, CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(out_is_longweekends#348, 0, 0), true) THEN true ELSE false END AS out_is_longweekends#344, CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(in_is_holiday#349, 0, 0), true) THEN true ELSE false END AS in_is_holiday#345, CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(in_is_longweekends#350, 0, 0), true) THEN true ELSE false END AS in_is_longweekends#346]\n +- SubqueryAlias f\n +- SubqueryAlias t\n +- Project [outboundlegid#208, inboundlegid#209, agent#205, querydatetime#231, CASE WHEN ((type#57 = HOLIDAY) && ((out_date#267 >= start#55) && (out_date#267 <= end#56))) THEN true ELSE false END AS out_is_holiday#347, CASE WHEN ((type#57 = LONG_WEEKENDS) && ((out_date#267 >= start#55) && (out_date#267 <= end#56))) THEN true ELSE false END AS out_is_longweekends#348, CASE WHEN ((type#57 = HOLIDAY) && ((in_date#304 >= start#55) && (in_date#304 <= end#56))) THEN true ELSE false END AS in_is_holiday#349, CASE WHEN ((type#57 = LONG_WEEKENDS) && ((in_date#304 >= start#55) && (in_date#304 <= end#56))) THEN true ELSE false END AS in_is_longweekends#350]\n +- Join Cross\n :- SubqueryAlias f\n : +- SubqueryAlias flights\n : +- Project [Id#198, QueryTaskId#199, QueryOriginPlace#200, QueryOutboundDate#201, QueryInboundDate#202, QueryCabinClass#203, QueryCurrency#204, Agent#205, QuoteAgeInMinutes#206, Price#207, OutboundLegId#208, InboundLegId#209, OutDeparture#210, OutArrival#211, OutDuration#212, OutJourneyMode#213, OutStops#214, OutCarriers#215, OutOperatingCarriers#216, NumberOutStops#217, NumberOutCarriers#218, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#219, InDeparture#220, InArrival#221, ... 12 more fields]\n : +- Project [Id#198, QueryTaskId#199, QueryOriginPlace#200, QueryOutboundDate#201, QueryInboundDate#202, QueryCabinClass#203, QueryCurrency#204, Agent#205, QuoteAgeInMinutes#206, Price#207, OutboundLegId#208, InboundLegId#209, OutDeparture#210, OutArrival#211, OutDuration#212, OutJourneyMode#213, OutStops#214, OutCarriers#215, OutOperatingCarriers#216, NumberOutStops#217, NumberOutCarriers#218, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#219, InDeparture#220, InArrival#221, ... 11 more fields]\n : +- LogicalRDD [Id#198, QueryTaskId#199, QueryOriginPlace#200, QueryOutboundDate#201, QueryInboundDate#202, QueryCabinClass#203, QueryCurrency#204, Agent#205, QuoteAgeInMinutes#206, Price#207, OutboundLegId#208, InboundLegId#209, OutDeparture#210, OutArrival#211, OutDuration#212, OutJourneyMode#213, OutStops#214, OutCarriers#215, OutOperatingCarriers#216, NumberOutStops#217, NumberOutCarriers#218, NumberOutOperatingCarriers#219, InDeparture#220, InArrival#221, ... 10 more fields]\n +- SubqueryAlias h\n +- SubqueryAlias holidays\n +- LogicalRDD [start#55, end#56, type#57]\n"
```

Comment: can you share sample data for holidays table.. also is scala solution ok for you?

Comment: @stack0114106, yes scala is fine. Added some example data

Comment: How big is the holidays table? Why can't you do a `join`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be overkill in trying to reduce the code using foldLeft/reduce functions for adding these 4 columns. To me, it appears to get some stuffs done by constructing the SQL strings rather than falling back to dataframe operations. Check this out

```
scala> val holiday = Seq(("2019-01-01","2019-01-01","HOLIDAY"),
     | ("2019-02-05","2019-02-06","HOLIDAY"),
     | ("2019-03-16","2019-03-24","HOLIDAY"),
     | ("2019-04-19","2019-04-19","HOLIDAY"),
     | ("2019-10-04","2019-10-04","HOLIDAY"),
     | ("2019-08-08","2019-08-13","LONG_WEEKENDS"),
     | ("2019-10-25","2019-10-29","LONG_WEEKENDS"),
     | ("2019-12-20","2020-01-02","LONG_WEEKENDS")
     | ).toDF("start","end","type")
holiday: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [start: string, end: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val flight = Seq(("25997661","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"),  
     | ("25997658","2019-02-05","2019-02-12"), // modified to get "true" values
     | ("25997659","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"),
     | ("25997662","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"),
     | ("25997663","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"),
     | ("25997657","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"),
     | ("25997660","2019-02-08","2019-02-12"),
     | ("25997397","2019-02-08","2019-02-12")
     | ).toDF("id","out_date","in_date")
flight: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, out_date: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val df = flight.crossJoin(holiday).withColumn("out_date",to_date('out_date)).withColumn("in_date",to_date('in_date)).withColumn("start",to_date('start)).withColumn("endx",to_date('end)).withColumn("typex",'type)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, out_date: date ... 6 more fields]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("jiew")

scala> val od_holiday = """ case when out_date >= start and out_date <= endx and typex='HOLIDAY' then true else false end out_date_is_holiday """
od_holiday: String = " case when out_date >= start and out_date <= endx and typex='HOLIDAY' then true else false end out_date_is_holiday "

scala> val od_longweek = """ case when out_date >= start and out_date <= endx and typex='LONG_WEEKENDS' then true else false end out_date_is_longweekends """
od_longweek: String = " case when out_date >= start and out_date <= endx and typex='LONG_WEEKENDS' then true else false end out_date_is_longweekends "

scala> val id_holiday = """ case when in_date >= start and in_date <= endx and typex='HOLIDAY' then true else false end in_date_is_holiday """
id_holiday: String = " case when in_date >= start and in_date <= endx and typex='HOLIDAY' then true else false end in_date_is_holiday "

scala> val id_longweek = """ case when in_date >= start and in_date <= endx and typex='LONG_WEEKENDS' then true else false end in_date_is_longweekends """
id_longweek: String = " case when in_date >= start and in_date <= endx and typex='LONG_WEEKENDS' then true else false end in_date_is_longweekends "

scala> val sel_columns = Array(od_holiday,od_longweek,id_holiday,id_longweek).mkString(",")
sel_columns: String = " case when out_date >= start and out_date <= endx and typex='HOLIDAY' then true else false end out_date_is_holiday , case when out_date >= start and out_date <= endx and typex='LONG_WEEKENDS' then true else false end out_date_is_longweekends , case when in_date >= start and in_date <= endx and typex='HOLIDAY' then true else false end in_date_is_holiday , case when in_date >= start and in_date <= endx and typex='LONG_WEEKENDS' then true else false end in_date_is_longweekends "

scala> val new_columns = Array("out_date_is_holiday","out_date_is_longweekends","in_date_is_holiday","in_date_is_longweekends")
new_columns: Array[String] = Array(out_date_is_holiday, out_date_is_longweekends, in_date_is_holiday, in_date_is_longweekends)

scala> val group_sel_columns = new_columns.map( x => s"case when array_contains(collect_set("+x+"),true) then true else false end "+x )
group_sel_columns: Array[String] = Array(case when array_contains(collect_set(out_date_is_holiday),true) then true else false end out_date_is_holiday, case when array_contains(collect_set(out_date_is_longweekends),true) then true else false end out_date_is_longweekends, case when array_contains(collect_set(in_date_is_holiday),true) then true else false end in_date_is_holiday, case when array_contains(collect_set(in_date_is_longweekends),true) then true else false end in_date_is_longweekends)

scala> val group_sel_columns_str = group_sel_columns.mkString(",")
group_sel_columns_str: String = case when array_contains(collect_set(out_date_is_holiday),true) then true else false end out_date_is_holiday,case when array_contains(collect_set(out_date_is_longweekends),true) then true else false end out_date_is_longweekends,case when array_contains(collect_set(in_date_is_holiday),true) then true else false end in_date_is_holiday,case when array_contains(collect_set(in_date_is_longweekends),true) then true else false end in_date_is_longweekends

scala> spark.sql( s""" with t1 ( select t.*, ${sel_columns}  from jiew t) select id,out_date,in_date, ${group_sel_columns_str}  from t1 group by id,out_date,in_date """).show(false)
+--------+----------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|id      |out_date  |in_date   |out_date_is_holiday|out_date_is_longweekends|in_date_is_holiday|in_date_is_longweekends|
+--------+----------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
|25997663|2019-02-08|2019-02-12|false              |false                   |false             |false                  |
|25997657|2019-02-08|2019-02-12|false              |false                   |false             |false                  |
|25997662|2019-02-08|2019-02-12|false              |false                   |false             |false                  |
|25997397|2019-02-08|2019-02-12|false              |false                   |false             |false                  |
|25997660|2019-02-08|2019-02-12|false              |false                   |false             |false                  |
|25997659|2019-02-08|2019-02-12|false              |false                   |false             |false                  |
|25997661|2019-02-08|2019-02-12|false              |false                   |false             |false                  |
|25997658|2019-02-05|2019-02-12|true               |false                   |false             |false                  |
+--------+----------+----------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------+-----------------------+


scala> val df2 = spark.sql( s""" with t1 ( select t.*, ${sel_columns}  from jiew t) select id,out_date,in_date, ${group_sel_columns_str}  from t1 group by id,out_date,in_date """)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: string, out_date: date ... 5 more fields]

scala>
```

Comment: Hi, I am wondering, is the CROSS JOIN suitable if the flights table has trillions or rows? In reality the where clause should reduce it to perhaps XX millions of rows tho. Last time I checked, I think the join is done first ...

Comment: But the holiday table will be small I suppose.. we could also try to broadcast the holiday table and there wont be much hit to the performance

Comment: Ok I am adapting the code to see how it works, thank you

Comment: replace ````f.*```` in the select query with the actual column names... since you are using the group by you need to specify only those columns in select clause

Comment: Found its a problem with trailing comma. But now I get Futures timeout exception https://pastebin.com/5x73zKtq ... I think the join is too large?

Comment: It seems to be some internal error.. does it repeat  when  rerrun?

Comment: Yes. Any idea how do I read this (like the exaplain part)? Any clue which part is slow?