# pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nextraneous > input 'xxx' expecting {')', ','}

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 main tables: flights and holidays.

Flights is identified by: `outboundlegid, inboundlegid, agent, querydatetime`. The additional columns applicable to the question are `out_date, in_date`. They indicate when is the flight departing and the return date.

And Holidays with the columns `start, end, type`

I want to determine if the flight out/in date is intersecting any thing from holidays table.

I followed some suggestion from [PySpark: How to add columns whose data come from a query (similar to subquery for each row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571913/pyspark-how-to-add-columns-whose-data-come-from-a-query-similar-to-subquery-fo) to determine if the out/in dates intersect any holiday.

However, I am getting: "pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nextraneous

> input 'outboundlegid' expecting {')', ','}(line 35, pos 12)". Whats wrong here?
>
> File "script_2019-02-08-10-46-14.py", line 182, in  """) File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1549622095592_0002/container_1549622095592_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py",
>   line 603, in sql File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1549622095592_0002/container_1549622095592_0002_01_000001/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call** File
>   "/mnt/yarn/usercache/root/appcache/application_1549622095592_0002/container_1549622095592_0002_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 73, in deco pyspark.sql.utils.ParseException: u"\nextraneous
>   input 'outboundlegid' expecting {')', ','}(line 35, pos 12)\n\n== SQL
>   ==\n\n WITH t (\n SELECT \n f.outboundlegid,\n f.inboundlegid,\n f.agent,\n f.querydatetime,\n CASE WHEN type = 'HOLIDAY' AND (out_date
>   BETWEEN start AND end)\n THEN true\n ELSE false\n END
>   out_is_holiday,\n CASE WHEN type = 'LONG_WEEKENDS' AND (out_date
>   BETWEEN start AND end)\n THEN true\n ELSE false\n END
>   out_is_longweekends,\n CASE WHEN type = 'HOLIDAY' AND (in_date BETWEEN
>   start AND end)\n THEN true\n ELSE false\n END in_is_holiday,\n CASE
>   WHEN type = 'LONG_WEEKENDS' AND (in_date BETWEEN start AND end)\n THEN
>   true\n ELSE false\n END in_is_longweekends\n FROM flights f\n CROSS
>   JOIN holidays h\n )\n SELECT \n f.*,\n t1.out_is_holiday,\n
>   t1.out_is_longweekends,\n t1.in_is_holiday,\n t1.in_is_longweekends,\n
>   FROM (\n SELECT \n outboundlegid,\n------------^^^\n inboundlegid,\n
>   agent,\n querydatetime,\n CASE WHEN
>   array_contains(collect_set(out_is_holiday), true)\n THEN true\n ELSE
>   false\n END out_is_holiday,\n CASE WHEN
>   array_contains(collect_set(out_is_longweekends), true)\n THEN true\n
>   ELSE false\n END out_is_longweekends,\n CASE WHEN
>   array_contains(collect_set(in_is_holiday), true)\n THEN true\n ELSE
>   false\n END in_is_holiday,\n CASE WHEN
>   array_contains(collect_set(in_is_longweekends), true)\n THEN true\n
>   ELSE false\n

Whats the problem here?

```
resultDf = spark.sql("""
    WITH t (
        SELECT  
            f.outboundlegid,
            f.inboundlegid,
            f.agent,
            f.querydatetime,
            CASE WHEN type = 'HOLIDAY' AND (out_date BETWEEN start AND end)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END out_is_holiday,
            CASE WHEN type = 'LONG_WEEKENDS' AND (out_date BETWEEN start AND end)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END out_is_longweekends,
            CASE WHEN type = 'HOLIDAY' AND (in_date BETWEEN start AND end)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END in_is_holiday,
            CASE WHEN type = 'LONG_WEEKENDS' AND (in_date BETWEEN start AND end)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END in_is_longweekends
        FROM flights f
        CROSS JOIN holidays h
    )
    SELECT 
        f.*,
        t1.out_is_holiday,
        t1.out_is_longweekends,
        t1.in_is_holiday,
        t1.in_is_longweekends,
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            outboundlegid,   # <<< I am guessing something wrong with this? But Why?
            inboundlegid,
            agent,
            querydatetime,
            CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(out_is_holiday), true)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END out_is_holiday,
            CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(out_is_longweekends), true)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END out_is_longweekends,
            CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(in_is_holiday), true)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END in_is_holiday,
            CASE WHEN array_contains(collect_set(in_is_longweekends), true)
                THEN true
                ELSE false
                END in_is_longweekends
        FROM t
        GROUP BY 
            querydatetime, 
            outboundlegid,
            inboundlegid,
            agent
        LIMIT 100000
    ) t1
    INNER JOIN flights f
    ON t1.querydatetime = f.querydatetime
    AND t1.outboundlegid = f.outboundlegid
    AND t1.inboundlegid = f.inboundlegid
    AND t1.agent = f.agent
    INNER JOIN agents a
    ON f.agent = a.id
    INNER JOIN airports p
    ON f.querydestinationplace = p.airportId
""")
```

Comment: Dangling comma after `t1.in_is_longweekends` and before   `FROM (`.

Comment: @user10465355, you can put that as an answer and I mark it answered

Comment: I am glad it helped, but it is nothing more than a typo, so let's call it a problem that can no longer be reproduced :)